# What is if (c >> a & 1) does mean?

Tags: c, binary, signals

I'm trying to understand what is this condition mean.

Does it mean after shifting the value it will be equal to 1?

I mean does it mean --> if (c >> a is 1)

---

Note: `c >> a & 1` same as `(c >> a) & 1`.

Comment: It checks whether the `a'th` bit of `c` is raised in terms of bitpattern.

Comment: Abrar X, post the _type_ of `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitwise AND operate on *bits*, so the possibilities are :

```
1101 & 0001 => 0001

0001 & 0001 => 0001

1010 & 0001 => 0000

0000 & 0001 => 0000
```

Now, on C, anything that's not a zero is treated as `true`, so the statement means "if after shifting the least significant bit is 1", or perhaps "if after shifting the value is odd" if you're dealing with odd-even operation.

Answer (score 0):

It executes the following statement or block if bit *a* of value *c* is true.

```
              a+1  a  a-1           1   0
       ... --+---+---+---+-- ... -+---+---+
             | z | y | x |        | q | p |
       ... --+---+---+---+-- ... -+---+---+


                             ... -+---+---+
>> a                              | z | y |
                             ... -+---+---+


                             ... -+---+---+
&& 1                              | 0 | y |
                             ... -+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

`>>` has higher operator precedence than `&`.

So `c >> a & 1` means "shift the value `c` by `a` bits to the right, then check if the lowest bit of the shifted value is set. To single out certain bit values like this is known as *bit masking* and `1` in this case is the mask.